# Rails System Wide Unique ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, uniqueidentifier

I'm working on a Rails 4 app and i want to give every record in my rails app a unique id automatically upon creation. I am using `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(7, false)` to create the id. I read around and i decided to create my own `active_record.rb` config/initializer to create the ids automatically. In active_record.rb i have

```
module UniqueID
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  self.primary_key = 'unique_id'
  before_create :set_unique_id

  protected

  def set_unique_id
    loop do
      self.unique_id = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(7, false)
      break unless self.find_by_unique_id(self.unique_id)
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, UniqueID)
```

but when i run a db:migrate i get

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"myapp_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"myapp", "password"=>nil}
rake aborted!
undefined method `primary_key=' for UniqueID:Module
/Users/me/RubymineProjects/myapp/config/initializers/active_record.rb:4:in `<module:UniqueID>'
/Users/me/RubymineProjects/myapp/config/initializers/active_record.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/me/RubymineProjects/myapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate:reset => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any idea why this is happening and is there a better way to do this?

Update: When using include i then get:

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `unique_id=' for #<ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration version: "20130623171324">
```

Migration

```
class AddUniqueIdToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :unique_id, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: have you created a migration to add "unique_id" to each table? And, if so, have you run it?

Comment: I didnt create a migration i just added t.string :unique_id to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to move the logic inside an included block? Like this

```
included do
  self.primary_key = 'unique_id'
  before_create :set_unique_id
end
```

-- EDIT --

You could also try changing the method to

```
def set_unique_id
  loop do
    self.id = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(7, false)
    break unless self.find(self.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: You have to add an :unique_id field to every table in your system using a migration.

Comment: I updated my question with my migration file and i get the same result.

Comment: I tried that and its getting caught on self.find_by_unique_id(self.id) so i changed it to self.find_by_id(self.id) and 'undefined method `find_by_id''. I dont know why its this difficult to ass a unique id.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that should be fixed now. It's kind of a hack because we are overriding Rails default id behaviour..

Comment: I changed it and now i get rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `find' for #<ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration version: "20130623171324">

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32242/discussion-between-ju-liu-and-ny95)

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping it in an `included` block should work. Like so:

```
included do
  primary_key = 'unique_id'
  before_create :set_unique_id
end
```